# Regex get part from "=" first occurence to left and rest to right

Tags: regex

I can't resolve this case:

```
hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/test/r/abc=1/day=1
```

Need to extract

```
/abc=1/day=1
```

So in this case we need to start from first occurence of `=` character and then get everything to the left till first occurence of `/` character and rest to right.

For now I only know how to get everything to right with this: `=.*`

Comment: What language/flavor (add a tag), and show your actual attempt.

Comment: Is this OK `^.+\K/.+?=.+?/.+=.+$` for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/test/r/abc=1/day=1"  | grep -oE '[^/]+=.*'
```